# XPerfViewer with the new Storport Provider?

Tags: windows, performance, xperf

Does anyone know of a way to parse out disk latency information from the new Storport provider with XPerfViewer (or any other tool)?

I used the following article to capture a trace:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/04/22/etw-storport.aspx

This does give me a series of events in .etl format that XPerfViewer will plot as dots over time, but I'm hoping for a graph of disk latency.  The latency information is in the event, but I can't figure out a good way to pull it out and display it other than by sifting through the events one by one.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is also an interesting article regarding this.I wish there was a better GUI tool for this http://blogs.technet.com/b/robertsmith/archive/2012/02/07/analyzing-storage-performance-using-the-windows-performance-toolkit.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Tracerpt to dump the events out to a CSV file, then use Excel to graph it.

P.S: I wrote that fix, cool to see people using it! :)